# Inserting inside a Linked List

Tags: c++

My `insertAfter` function in the `LinkedList` is not working right.

I would really appreciate if someone could point out what's wrong with my code.

Thanks :)

Here is the list struct:

```
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};
```

and here is my function to insert inside the list:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T toInsert, T afterWhat)
{
 if(head!=NULL)    
 {
  ListItem<T>*p;
  p=head;
  while(p->next!=NULL)
  {
   if(p->value==afterWhat)
   {
    ListItem<T>*k;
    k=new ListItem<T>(toInsert);
    k->next=p->next;
    p->next=k;
    k->prev=p;
    k->next->prev=k;
   }
   else
    p=p->next;
  }
 }
 else
 {
  head= new ListItem<T>(toInsert);
 }
 //p=NULL;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a debugging service. Please learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Get the linked list working first without templates, then convert to templates.  A lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, no insertion should be made if, `afterWhat` is not found.

So, there will be no insertion when either: the list is empty, or `afterWhat` does not exist in the list.

Secondly, `while(p->next!=NULL)` loop will never check the last element of the list for `afterWhat`, because it ends its iterations one before the last.

So, if `afterWhat` is the last element in the list, it will go undetected.

Thirdly, the loop should be broken as soon as the insertion is done. Later the value of `p` can also determine whether `afterWhat` was found or not, and appropriate result can be displayed, if need be.

Fourth, now since the case of `afterWhat` being the last element is also being handled, we also need to check `p->next!=NULL` before making any changes to it, because it `p` could be the last element, in which case, nothing needs to be done for `p->next`.

Note that, you cannot insert an element in the `head` position using the `insertAfter` function, because nothing is before `head`, which can be used as `afterWhat` in this case.

The `insertAfter` function, should go like this:

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T toInsert, T afterWhat)
{
 if(head != NULL)
 {
  ListItem<T>*p;
  p=head;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
   if(p->value==afterWhat)
   {
    ListItem<T>*k;
    k = new ListItem<T>(toInsert);
    k->next = p->next;
    p->next = k;
    k->prev=p;
    if(k->next != NULL)
     k->next->prev = k;
    break;
   }
   else
    p = p->next;
  }

  if(p == NULL)
   cout<<"afterWhat, not found, hence no insertion made\n");
  else
   cout<<"Inserted!\n";
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<"List is empty, hence afterWhat, not found\n");
 }
}
```